# Could not find java.dll and Java SE

Tags: java

I have just installed jdk-9.0.1 on windows and while checking the version on cmd, got the following error :

```
C:\Users\hp>java -version
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

I had already set JAVA_HOME variable and updated the path but it still shows the same. :(

```
C:\Users\hp>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
```

Could find the solution for the following error, but it doesn't work in my case.

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7.0_01', but '1.7' is required.
```

Its the first time I'm installing java in this system so it might not probably be a mistake of existing java version.

Answer (score 0):

remove "jdk" from you JAVA_HOME path

Comment: Still they show the same error.

Comment: Try rebooting your system , In my case reboot helped